# Lebesgue Integral Tranlation Invariant/Change in Variable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We use this property (obvious fact) in class to prove one of the Corollary 4(page 113 Royden 4th ed) but then I try to prove it at home and I realize it gives me difficulties:

**For real numbers $a < b$ and $\frac{1}{n} >0$ show that if $f$ is integrable over $[a + \frac{1}{n}, b+ \frac{1}{n}]$ then $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x+\frac{1}{n}) = \int_{a+\frac{1}{n}}^{b +\frac{1}{n}} f(x)$$**

**My way of doing it:**
First I have to prove that $f$ is integrable  over $[a + \frac{1}{n}, b+ \frac{1}{n}]$ (I am having problem proving this, can anyone help)

Then, I think we have to use translation invariant property:
$\int f(x)dx = \int f(x+1/n) dx$ (i can prove this)

Now we have to use change in variable and combine these two steps (again having difficulties).

Can anyone help connecting these parts. Thanks

Comment: Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval, and let $\phi:[a,b]\to[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$ be a continuous monotone increasing function. Let $f:[\phi(a),\phi(b)]\to{\Bbb R}$ be a Riemann integrable function on $[\phi(a),\phi(b)]$. The $f\circ\phi:[a,b]\to{\Bbb R}$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ and 
$$
\int_{[a,b]}f\circ\phi\ d\phi=\int_{[\phi(a),\phi(b)]}f. \tag{1}
$$

Comment: The integrability of $f$ over $[a+1/n,b+1/n]$ is assumption. If you are assuming it, you don't have to prove it;-)

Comment: @iiivooo, you are right, my bad i did miss the word "if"

Comment: @RaziehNoori, can you expend on how i apply this to my case, i am not familiar with this ( i assume theorem) does it have a name, i don't think we studied yet, or I don't remember, thanks

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1338515231